# What is the difference between plain string and string from variable

Tags: shell, eslint

I am trying to write simple `shell` script which will run linter on many files. I stored all my file names in one long string and then also removed all potential `/n` signs from it. Then I run linter with name of these files hard-coded and take from variable. For hard-coded paths my linter work and can find those files but for path of these files stored in variable it can not.

Here is what I tried:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
all_files_to_commit=$(git diff --name-only --cached)
ends_with_ts=".*\.ts$"
ends_with_scss=".*\.scss$"
all_ts_files=""
all_scss_files=""
for file in $all_files_to_commit
do
  if echo "$file" | grep "$ends_with_ts"; then
    all_ts_files="${all_ts_files}${file} "
  fi
  if echo "$file" | grep "$ends_with_scss"; then
    all_scss_files="${all_scss_files}${file} "
  fi
done
all_ts_files=$(echo "$all_ts_files" | tr -d "\n")
echo "All files in one string"
echo "$all_ts_files"
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/components/List/List.ts src/views/Calculator/Calculator.ts --quiet
./node_modules/.bin/eslint "$all_ts_files" --quiet
```

Do you have any idea why those paths can be different and how can I fix this?

> I also tried this script without line which remove`\n` signs

**Output:**

```
All files in one string
src/components/List/List.ts src/views/Calculator/Calculator.ts 

/home/kaczor6418/Desktop/projects/expressions-calculator/src/components/List/List.ts
  24:9  error  Delete `·············`  prettier/prettier

/home/kaczor6418/Desktop/projects/expressions-calculator/src/views/Calculator/Calculator.ts
  53:9  error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead  no-var
  54:9  error  Delete `············`                     prettier/prettier

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)
  3 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.11.0

No files matching the pattern "src/components/List/List.ts src/views/Calculator/Calculator.ts " were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the quotes in

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint "$all_ts_files" --quiet
```

the found file names are concatenated into one filename with spaces.
The string `src/components/List/List.ts src/views/Calculator/Calculator.ts`  is not representing a file (you do not have a directory named `List.ts src`).
With the given filenames you can remove the quotes:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint $all_ts_files --quiet
```

When you are making a string from a list of filenames, you can not see when a space (or newline) is part of a filename.
In your example you could try using arrays:

```
all_files_to_commit=($(git diff --name-only --cached))
# change code here when you want to use arrays
./node_modules/.bin/eslint ${all_ts_files[@]} --quiet
```

or use something like

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint $(git diff --name-only --cached | grep ts$) --quiet
```

You can support spaces in filenames (not newlines)  with

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint $(git diff --name-only --cached | sed -n '/ts$/ s/.*/"&"/p' ) --quiet
```